# Jquery div content change

Tags: html, jquery

I bought ready-made software from somewhere and I only have js and css access.I am very newbie to codes and need your help.

I want to change all div text to " 24 SAATTE KARGODA " if right_line span is equal "Aynı Gün" .

There is 3 span coming but i want to cancel the others.

```
<div class="Formline" id="divTahminiTeslimatSuresi" style="">
<span class="left_line lineTitle">Tahmini Teslim Süresi</span>
<span class="center_line lineTitle">:</span>
<span class="right_line" id="spnTahminiTeslimSuresi">Aynı Gün</span>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: please follow the code of conduct of SO (https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) an Element which [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) matches a certain string (`"Aynı Gün"`)

```js
const cargo24h = "24 SAATTE KARGODA";

$(".Formline").each(function() {
  // $(this) refers to the currently iterating .Formline $Element
  const $rightLine = $(this).find(".right_line");
  if ($rightLine.text() === "Aynı Gün") {
    $(this).html(cargo24h);
    // $rightLine.text(cargo24h); // Or use this one
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="Formline" id="divTahminiTeslimatSuresi" style="">
  <span class="left_line lineTitle">Tahmini Teslim Süresi</span>
  <span class="center_line lineTitle">:</span>
  <span class="right_line">Aynı Gün</span>
</div>

<div class="Formline" id="divTahminiTeslimatSuresi" style="">
  <span class="left_line lineTitle">Tahmini Teslim Süresi</span>
  <span class="center_line lineTitle">:</span>
  <span class="right_line">Ertesi gün</span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: if that's the case - don't use the same ID (spnTahminiTeslimSuresi) on multiple elements. ID Must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the `:contains()` pseudo-class.

Like that:

```
$('.Formline span:contains(Aynı Gün)').text('24 SAATTE KARGODA');
```

[Read more](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```js
$('.Formline span:contains(Aynı Gün)').text('24 SAATTE KARGODA');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Formline" id="divTahminiTeslimatSuresi" style="">
  <span class="left_line lineTitle">Tahmini Teslim Süresi</span>
  <span class="center_line lineTitle">:</span>
  <span class="right_line" id="spnTahminiTeslimSuresi">Aynı Gün</span>
</div>
```